# Is it possible for a html textbox to populate a sharepoint column in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, content-editor-web-part, html

Here is the scenario:

SharePoint 2010 doesn't have a back button, this makes it difficult when a user messes up in a branched survey.

I have created a little JavaScript embedded html page that I was going to add into SharePoint content editor.

This is where my problem occurs, within the HTML I have "textareas" which users will write their response, I would like this response in the textarea to populate a column in a SharePoint list. Each textarea has its own unique name, which is why I'm thinking this is possible I'm just not sure how.

To give you an example:

With whom am I speaking?

```
<textarea name="Name" rows="2" cols="60"></textarea>
```

The agent would write the name of the person they are speaking with and it would populate a column within a new list item.

Even if I had to have a button with a JavaScript backend which OnClick  at the very end of all the questions/branches added each textarea to the list that would work...

If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to CSOM vs SpServices, CSOM is the appropriate framework to use if you don't need cross site collection communication. Full discussion here: http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15

If you feel the CSOM is a bit confusing, I've built a library which makes it much easier. You can find it here: https://github.com/monzerhijazi/SpUtil

It wraps the CSOM but still gives you full control.

Here's a snippet:

```
var list = new SpListUtil("ListName", { webUrl: "http://weburl" });

list.create({
Title: "Some title"
//fieldName : fieldVal
},
{
  success: function(item){
    //do something with item
  },
  error: function(err){
  }
});
```

Keep in mind all of these libraries require your code to run inside SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the REST API and javascript to update a SharePoint List.

I think this thread has your answer.

[SP2010 Javascript REST API: updating list item using MERGE and POST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70666/sp2010-javascript-rest-api-updating-list-item-using-merge-and-post)

Here is some additional information.

SPServices is a jQuery library which abstracts SharePoint's Web Services and makes them easier to use. 
http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Using the REST Interface
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx